# Make count data frame

Tags: r, count, statistics, apply

I have data that I work with, which is count data i.e. every date+time combination represents a data point. So my current data frame looks as follows:

```
  DATE        TIME
1 2014-02-15  15:02
2 2014-02-15  15:12
3 2014-04-15  02:02
4 2014-05-15  11:02
5 2014-06-15  15:42
6 2014-06-15  16:02
....
```

Now I want to have a new DF that counts how many data points there are per hour for a particular date. Something like below:

```
  DATE        HOUR    COUNT
1 2014-02-15  15      2
2 2014-04-15  02      1
3 2014-05-15  11      1
4 2014-06-15  15      1
5 2014-06-15  16      1
....
```

I want to do this so that I can make a boxplot with x = hour of the day, y = number of data points (over a year). Tried to do it with nested for loops, but it didn't work.

---

EDIT: and if possible, the date/hour combination where there is no data point should be in the data frame, but with COUNT = 0.

Comment: The second part that you just edited in is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
options(stringsAsFactors = F)

data = read.table(text  = 
"                  1 2014-02-15  15:02
                   2 2014-02-15  15:12
                   3 2014-04-15  02:02
                   4 2014-05-15  11:02
                   5 2014-06-15  15:42
                   6 2014-06-15  16:02")


colnames(data) = c("index", "date", "time")

table(data$date)

 # 2014-02-15 2014-04-15 2014-05-15 2014-06-15 
 #     2          1          1          2 

table(data$date, data$time)

fz = table(data$date, substr(data$time, 1,2))
print(fz)   

 #            02 11 15 16
 # 2014-02-15  0  0  2  0
 # 2014-04-15  1  0  0  0
 # 2014-05-15  0  1  0  0
 # 2014-06-15  0  0  1  1
```

If you want to reshape your data you can do the following:

```
library(reshape)

otherFormat = melt(fz)
colnames(otherFormat) = c("date","hour", "frequency")

print(otherFormat)

#          date hour frequency
# 1  2014-02-15    2         0
# 2  2014-04-15    2         1
# 3  2014-05-15    2         0
# 4  2014-06-15    2         0
# 5  2014-02-15   11         0
# 6  2014-04-15   11         0
# 7  2014-05-15   11         1
# 8  2014-06-15   11         0
# 9  2014-02-15   15         2
# 10 2014-04-15   15         0
# 11 2014-05-15   15         0
# 12 2014-06-15   15         1
# 13 2014-02-15   16         0
# 14 2014-04-15   16         0
# 15 2014-05-15   16         0
# 16 2014-06-15   16         1
```

Comment: Fyi, you can reshape by wrapping `table` in `as.data.frame`, like `as.data.frame( table(data$date, substr(data$time, 1,2)) )` I think you forgot to define this `fz` object, by the way.

Comment: Think this exactly what I mean! Thank you! Just one more question, my data only shows the dates/times were there are data points. But if I want to show that at a certain time there are no data points, how can I add these? So I would like to have the data frame run from two dates, display all 24 hours as different rows and if count for that data/hour combination is 0 it has to say freq = 0, not be left out.

Comment: Thank you Frank! I always used the melt directly.. Great tip! And yes I forgot to define the fz.

Comment: Glad I can help Guido.  For this you could first try to find the all timestamps of your period:    `allTimeStamps = seq(start_timestamp, end_timestamp, by = "day)` then find the missing ones  
  `extraTimeStamps = allTimeStamps[!allTimeStamps %in% otherFormat$date]` . Then insert that into your data frame.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the most readable way:

**edited to answer your updated question**

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- date.data %>%
  group_by(
    DATE = as.Date(DATE), 
    HOUR = as.numeric(str_sub(TIME, 1, 2))
    ) %>%
  tally 

# create a data frame with all dates/hours
expand.grid(
  # include all dates from first to last
  DATE = seq.Date(min(df$DATE), max(df$DATE), "day"),
  HOUR = 0:23
) %>% 
  arrange(DATE) %>%
  left_join(df, by = c("DATE", "HOUR"))
```

Comment: a cpl more lines with `tidyr::expand` and `left_join` in the mix wld also incl the solution to the OP's edited request.

Answer (score 1):

Additional option would be the following. First, you create a column for hour in `mutate()`. Then, you count how many data points exist by `DATE` and `hour` in `count()`. Once you ungroup the data, you join two data frames to create your desired outcome. The `expand.grid()` part creates all combination of DATE and hour (00 to 23). Since you have 02 for 2, I used `c(paste0("0", 0:9), 10:23))`. Finally, you replace NA with 0 in the final `mutate()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(data.table)

mutate(mydf, DATE, hour = stri_extract_first(TIME, regex = "\\d+")) %>%
count(DATE, hour) %>%
ungroup %>%
right_join(expand.grid(DATE = unique(.$DATE),
                       hour = c(paste0("0", 0:9), 10:23))) %>%
mutate(n = replace(n, is.na(n), 0))

# A bit of outcome
#         DATE hour n
#1  2014-02-15   00 0
#2  2014-04-15   00 0
#3  2014-05-15   00 0
#4  2014-06-15   00 0
#5  2014-02-15   01 0
```

Using data.table, you could do the same operation. You create a column for `hour` and count the number of data points by `DATE` and `hour`. Then, you want to merge `temp` with a data table which has all combination of DATE and hours (00 to 23). You can create the data table using `CJ()`. Once you finish the merge process, You replace `NA` with `0` in the column for count (`total`).

```
setDT(mydf)[, hour := stri_extract_first(TIME, regex = "\\d+")][,
            list(total = .N), by = list(DATE, hour)] -> temp

merge(temp,
      CJ(DATE = unique(mydf$DATE), hour = c(paste0("0", 0:9), 10:23)),
      by = c("DATE", "hour"), all = TRUE)[, total := replace(total, is.na(total), 0)][]

#          DATE hour total
# 1: 2014-02-15   02     0
# 2: 2014-02-15   11     0
# 3: 2014-02-15   15     2
# 4: 2014-02-15   16     0
# 5: 2014-02-15   00     0
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(DATE = structure(c(16116, 16116, 16175, 16205, 
16236, 16236), class = "Date"), TIME = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("02:02", "11:02", "15:02", "15:12", "15:42", 
"16:02"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("DATE", 
"TIME"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a few ways, but I suspect that the easiest way is for you to use `table`. Using 'table', you can return a frequency on the dates. This is basically just a count of the dates in the data frame.

You can do the same thing after extracting the hour - you can even nest it by doing `table(DF$DATE,DF$HOUR)`. Using `as.data.frame` would get you a listing somewhat like what you are looking for.

EDITED TO ADD: In response to your edit of the question, you can use a `factor` level to get the zero levels in the `table` statement. `table` respects your factor levels by including them in it's output, even if it is not found in the input (in fact, I believe that `table` coerces the input into factors on the back side).

Example code:

```
# Set options and load example data
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
date.data <- data.frame(DATE = c("2014-02-15","2014-02-15","2014-04-15","2014-05-15","2014-06-15","2014-06-15"),
                        TIME = c("15:02","15:12","02:02","11:02","15:42","16:02"))

# Extract the hour
date.data$HOUR <- sapply(X = strsplit(x = date.data$TIME,split = ":"),FUN = `[[`,1)

# Now, set the hours as a factor level - this will allow table() to fill the data in as you are requesting
date.data$HOUR <- factor(x = date.data$HOUR,
                         levels = c("00","01","02","03","04","05",
                                    "06","07","08","09","10","11",
                                    "12","13","14","15","16","17",
                                    "18","19","20","21","22","23"),
                         labels = c("00","01","02","03","04","05",
                                    "06","07","08","09","10","11",
                                    "12","13","14","15","16","17",
                                    "18","19","20","21","22","23"))

# Obtain the first table of interest
as.data.frame(table(date.data$DATE))

        Var1 Freq
1 2014-02-15    2
2 2014-04-15    1
3 2014-05-15    1
4 2014-06-15    2

# And the second table
as.data.frame(table(date.data$DATE,date.data$HOUR))

         Var1 Var2 Freq
1  2014-02-15   00    0
2  2014-04-15   00    0
3  2014-05-15   00    0
4  2014-06-15   00    0
5  2014-02-15   01    0
6  2014-04-15   01    0
7  2014-05-15   01    0
8  2014-06-15   01    0
....
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but it is not exactly what I mean (very close though). I need the frequency count of the date AND hour, so if I have two data points on hour 15.xx on 2014-02-15 the frequency should be 2. With your code I get two different frequency tables (one for date frequency and one for hour freq).

Comment: But...isn't the second one giving you what you need? It's date and hour together.